# Mulesoft - Netsuite integration - How to pass recrodRef value?

Tags: mule, netsuite

I am new to MuleSoft. Integrating with NetSuite Employee object. It has mandatory field called "subsidiary" of recordref type. From MuleSoft, using Tranform Message, how do I pass value to "Subsidiary" field of record ref type? This will be passed to NetSuite connector -> "Add Record" function.

Comment: I don't know Mulesoft (always used Jitterbit), but from everything I've seen it should just be a node in the target structure, for subsidiary.  That node should be able to accept Internal ID, External ID, or Name.